# What replaces MobiTex for sporadic low bandwidth usage?

Tags: wireless, cellphone, mobile

Back in the day I would use [MobiTex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobitex) for low bandwidth usage for devices that simply needed a few simple commands sent or received.

It now seems next to impossible to procure or use MobiText devices and it's possible that the whole network is being phased out.

For devices that simply need to report information (oil pumps, sprinklers) or things that need authenticated control (remote locks, pump controllers etc) what network has the ubiquity and low bandwidth requirements that [MobiTex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobitex) once dominated?

Comment: What is MobiText?

Comment: @LiorBilia Sorry my phone automatically changed the typing.. the correct word is MobiTex http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobitex

Answer (score 1):

There are few options, which depend largely on your budget:
GSM, 3G, WiMax (If available in your specific country) and proprietary network solutions in the ISM bands (433MHz or 868/915MHz). A MobiTex node can be implemented with a modern sub 1GHz    transceiver, GMSK is available in many of those devices from Maxim, TI, Nordic and others.

Answer (score 1):

I think most applications like yours have shifted over to using SMS ([Short Message Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Service)) via a cell-network modem module.